# Can anyone tell the query for the below scenario

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, mssql-jdbc

Input:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| DBA | Stored Procedure |
| DBA | Functions |
| DBA | Triggers |

Output:

| Col1 | Col2 |
| --- | --- |
| DBA | Stored Procedure, Functions, Triggers |

Comment: It's not even clear how you're supposed to get from input to output. Why does `DBA` disappear for these two rows? It looks like you're trying to manipulate a result set for display purposes, which is something much better done in client code than in the query itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
     case when substring(Col2,2,1)='u' then 'DBA' else '' end as Col1
    ,Col2
from yourtable
```

Comment: I stand my ground on this answer for entertainment purposes

Comment: It's correct but it works on a trick which you have taken u on Col2 using case statement what happened if two or more rows having U it can print there also right so that we have to write a query dynamically

Comment: If there are more rows, you should tell us what you are trying to do. I used "u" as a funnily  arbitrary example in order to indicate how blind we are trying to help you.

Comment: @HARISHVM There is no `case` _statement_, but there is a [`case`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) _expression_. And the answer isn't complete without `order by Substring( Col2, 3, 1 ) desc;`. If you have a better explanation of your requirements than "Input"/"Output" then we might be able to offer a more suitable answer. Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @HABO Isn't it contradictory to assume the explanation is not clear enough and also correct my answer?

Comment: I was not suggesting that _you_ change your answer. Instead I addressed the OP to point out that their detailed problem statement made no mention of the order of the results and that if one were to _assume_ that the "Output" was in the desired order then an `order by` clause was needed. The one I suggested is engineered as precisely as your `case` to arrive at the "Output" from the "Input" with no consideration of additional input data.

Comment: @HABO fair enough

Comment: Hi now I edited the question hope you understand the question....

Comment: Search for STRING_AGG or, if on version <2016, XML PATH concatenation